# Is there a Method to automatically open an adobe reader document with specific parts of the form already filled in?

Tags: javascript, command, adobe, line, acrobat

i want to make an automatic Form using adobe reader (i am using adobe acrobat for writing, but the user will use adobe reader) to track serial numbers. I deduced it is not possible to save a protocoll file with a javascript embedded into the form, due to security risks, so i had the idea to fill in the form using something like command line arguments in a .bat file, and than use the filled in form to save the protocol using a folder level javascript.
I have already found a few command line arguments for PDF, but all of those dont fill anything in, but rather make where to start in longer PDF, like which page, or which line.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Not from the command line. OLE automation may help out: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The way to client-side prefill a form is either via FDF (Forms Data Format) or its XML equivalent XFDF. In both cases, you do have the path to the base form. When you open the FDF in Acrobat (Reader), it will look for the base form, pull it in, and fill the according fields.

Practical hint: in order to get the correct syntax for the FDF, take your base form, fill it accordingly, and then export the data. The resulting file can be your template.